# A complex ordinary differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to see what instruments I could use to analyse the following ODE in the complex plane: $ \dot{z} = \exp(it)\cdot \bar{z}$. Where $z$ is a function of real valued time.

${{}}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ansatz $z=(u+iv)e^{it/2}$. Then your ODE becomes
$$
u'- \frac{v}{2}+i\left(v' + \frac{u}{2}\right) = u - iv
$$
Which is then a system of real ODEs
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u'\\
v'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2\\
-1/2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This can now be solved easily with standard techniques 
$$
\begin{cases}
u(t)= \frac{e^{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t }}{6} \left[c_1  \left((2 \sqrt{3} +3 )e^{\sqrt{3} t}-2 \sqrt{3}+3\right)+\sqrt{3}c_2 \left(e^{\sqrt{3} t}-1\right)\right]\\
v(t)= -\frac{e^{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  t}}{6}  \left[\sqrt{3} c_1 \left(e^{\sqrt{3} t}-1\right)
+c_2 \left(\left(2 \sqrt{3}-3\right) e^{\sqrt{3} t}+2 \sqrt{3}+3\right)
\right]
\end{cases}
$$
You can find $c_1, c_2$ by your initial conditions.